# How to redirect any request to directory AND strip args with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect any and all requests to a certain directory, even if the requests include arguments. For instance, I see that Google is listing a couple old links from an old blog as 404, but the links look like: example.com/stuff/?args .. So I feel like I need to redirect any request that goes to /stuff/ and also strip the args since they will produce their own 404's if they are left on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^stuff/?$ new-dir? [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Although this redirects as expected, it passed the arguments on. I am looking to strip all arguments. So modified it to read:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^stuff/?$ new/ [L,R,NC] 

But it still passed arguments.

Comment: `?` in the target URL strips out query string. So `new-dir?` (as in my answer) or `new-dir/?` should remove original query string for you.

Answer (score 0):

Or using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch ^/stuff/?.* /new/?
```

Comment: This throws this error: "The page isn't redirecting properly
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."